# Overloading static fields on Android

Tags: android, overloading, proguard, dalvik

In the [ProGuard docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html) it reads: "Google's Dalvik VM can't handle overloaded static fields."
As I understand it, something like this

```
public class A {
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(A.class.getName());
...
}

public class B extends A {
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(B.class.getName());
...
}
```

is bad on Android then. It this **really** true or did I get something wrong?
What are the implication then (I can run my code now but dex fails after proguard treatment)?

Comment: huh. it looks like you read the docs correctly. i didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it means you can't have two fields in class `A`, both named `log`, each of different types:

```
public class A {
  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(A.class.getName());
  private static final int log = 5;
  ...
}
```

You can't do this in source code, but tools like ProGuard can generate `.class` files like this that make decompilation more interesting.

You don't need to worry about your `B extends A` example; that would be a bug in Dalvik. Such a bug would be fixed very promptly!

Comment: This sounds reasonable. Until somebody comes up with an answer deemed "more correct", I will mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In Java the `final` keyword means that you can't override it, so this would be true.

Comment: You cannot override static fields in Java anyway, I was asking about overloading.